# Deployment on EC2 using poolparty and Chef server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

Does anyone have done the rails application deployment on EC2 using poolpary gems and Chef server(not Chef solo). Please share your experiences if you know some blogs or code links(except poolpartyrb.com and related to it).

The poolparty script must be able to launch an selected AMI instance with two EBS blocks(data and DB) use one elastic ip,fetch code repo and install Chef server on selected instance. Or if you have used Chef server for rails deployment please share your exp.

Thanks,
Pravin

Answer (score 4):

How far did you get with your pool party script?

- launching EC2 instances is explained in [this detailed example](http://auser.github.com/poolparty/amazon_ec2_setup.html)
- the EBS part is explained in [this github issue](https://github.com/auser/poolparty/issues/64)
- to deploy an application from git, use [chef's deploy resource](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Deploy+Resource)
- installing chef is done using `gem install chef`

Maybe you can share what you have and where exactly you're currently stuck.

Comment: hey Till, thanks for replay i was able to do first three u mention but problem was chef server but after that we move to apache it was likely solved, any ways after some month we moved to right scale for deployment so we are no more using poolparty ..

Comment: I moved the other way around - first we used RightScale, now we use a chef-based service called Scalarium.